# Testing SSH and Failed Servers

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, remote-server

I am currently working on a semester long project and it is in its final stages. It relies on using SSH (through python-paramiko) to connect to remote servers and fetch files. I would like to test:

- failed ssh connection
- a crashed server
- other connection issues that may arise

but I'm not really sure how to test a failed ssh connection. I tried removing ssh from the remote servers (I'm using virtual machines) but I decided I need to assume that the remote servers are set up correctly.

I also tried closing the SFTP port, but from what I read online you can't simply close a port down.

What would be would ways to test what I listed above? Any detail is welcomed since I'm hear to learn.

Comment: Could you disconnect the ssh connection at the server? http://askubuntu.com/questions/36113/how-to-log-off-an-user-from-ssh

Comment: @kponz maybe, I wouldn't know how off the top of my head but I'll do research and try it. I'm sure there is some sort of module that detects ssh connection and will give the option to kill it